# Excel Modelling Graph

Tags: python, excel

Please can you help me generate an Excel version of this data?
(please find images below)

##### Graph:

[image: graph]

Table:
[image: table]

I tried adding a trend line but it just gave a straight dotted line. I am trying to generate a curve.

When I tried selecting a logarithmic trend line, a dialog box appeared saying that the data contains zero or negative numbers hence a curve could not be formed.